# Fetch variable giving old data

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, discord.js

I'm trying to interact with an API using node-fetch and discord.js, so that the bot will reply to commands in Discord, and output the fetched information from the API.

However, it seems like it's not fetching the latest data for each command, and instead gives old data.

The expected behavior would be when I type `!players` it would return `There are 60 players online.` which works fine, but when I then refresh the API in browser and see the players attribute has changed from 60 to 61, and then go type `!players` again, it gives me the same `There are 60 players online.`.

What's the best way to make sure it always returns fresh data when I type the command?

You can find my current bot.js code here: https://jsfiddle.net/yvLodz4q/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fetch` method calling only once - when script started. If you want update this data you need to send request to the server with necessary data again when you need it.
For example, you can send request again in every call `!players` command.

Comment: You mean I should make a new fetch request in each `if (message.content === '!command') {`?

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. I guess I can do this for parts that requires updating more than when it's ran. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. And, i think, you're able to write your own command handler. 
Every command may have personal class - it's good to split the logic. If bot has a lot of commands and a lot of functions - split the logic with conditions not good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help! And yes, I will keep that in mind. Right now it's only for personal use and testing. Thanks!

Comment: Have a nice day. ;)

Comment: You as well :-)